# Multiple rows inside each table row (but only on certain columns)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm not quite sure how to word this so I've not managed to find an answer for it!

I want to create a table, where in certain columns there is multiple rows. As shown in the picture

[image]

How do I structure this?

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is imagine a table that listed all users in an application. Each row is a user, but I want to also have a sub row for each of the photos that a user may have.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multi-valued columns. As they do not satisfy first normal form (For detailed information about 1st Normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Let your table have the following columns:
(A,B,C,D)

As per the picture provided by you, I am making the following assumptions:

1) A is the primary key

2) C and D are both are multi-valued and the rows have values like (A1,B1,C1,D1),(A1,B1,C2,D2). That is for single A value we have multiple pairs of C and D.

Do comment if any of the assumption is wrong.

What you can do is make two tables.

TABLE1 (A,B)

TABLE2 (A,C,D)

Where A is the primary key in TABLE1 and foreign key in TABLE2.

As asked for a snippet,you can have tables like these:

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olCaP.png)

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, could you possibly provide a snippet example if you have a moment spare?

Comment: @S_R I have provided an instance of database tables